# Error when building uwp app in Release mode

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, release

I have this app, that builds and runs successfully in Debug mode, on both my local computer and on my Windows Phone device, when trying with the Release mode, I get these 3 errors :

> Error     Internal compiler error: One or more errors occurred.
>
> The non-generic type 'PInvoke.NTSTATUS.Code__PInvoke_Windows_Core'
>   cannot be used with type arguments
>   ...obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\Liberte.Windows.Interop\SafeTypes.g.cs    333
>
> The type or namespace name 'Value' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   ...obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\Liberte.Windows.Interop\SafeTypes.g.cs  333

The actual code where the two last errors are detected is an auto generated code under a file named `SafeTypes.g.cs` and the line where the errors is raised is :

```
namespace PInvoke
{
    [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgRedirectedType("PInvoke.NTSTATUS,PInvoke.Windows.Core, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e300f9f87f04a7a")]
    public unsafe partial struct NTSTATUS__PInvoke_Windows_Core
    {
        public global::PInvoke.NTSTATUS.Code__PInvoke_Windows_Core <Value>k__BackingField;
    }
}
```

I don't have any idea what does this mean, nor what should I do, any explanation and solution to this ?

**Update :**

Tried to Close VS, then Delete the Obj and the Bin content, rebuild again, but stuill have the same error.

I should mention maybe that I have reference to 2 other projects, one of them is a PCL project that uses PCLCrypto library, and the other one is a Universal App library that uses EntityFramework 7 pre-release with sqlight.

**Update 2:**

I tried to disable compilation with .Net native just to see what goes on, the release build succeeds, but the App crashes and quits just after startup.

**Update 3:**

I just discovered that the `PCLCrypto` library that I use in one of the two project I'm referencing, references two libs that are causing the problem, and they are mentioned in the errors above, I found this out when trying to uninstall the library to see if it is the cause of the problem :

[image]

I tried to rollback to a previous stable version, compiled in Debug mode, everything worked perfectly, when I try again Release mode with .Net native, I encounter a new [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162610/out-of-memory-error-when-compiling-uwp-app-in-release-mode-with-net-native) : `Out of memory`.

Comment: You should try close VS, delete /obj and /bin folder in Project root directory, then rebuild solution

Comment: @new01bie : thx for answering me, please check my update

Comment: Do you use .Net Native in Release mode? If "yes" - try remove it (in properties of main project) and try you way again.

Comment: @NikitaBondarenko thx for your comment, I've just tried that, the build succeeds, but that app crashes just after startup, any idea ??

Comment: Is the same exception or another?
Any errors in Output window? 
You say that "the App crashes and quits just after startup" - after what? After constructor in App.cs or after navigating to first (main) page?

Comment: @NikitaBondarenko yeah in the same execution (Release mode), no I don't get any errors in output window, I couldn't know exactly when the application crashes, but I suspect it's just when navigation to the first page where I start using my referenced projects I mentioned above

Comment: Try comment code which connected with referenced library and try again (build and start). 
Do you serialize\deserialize something after navigation to main page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning **Update 3**, it seems to be a bug with `.NET Native tool chain`, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto/issues/81#issuecomment-200078437) on `PCLCrypto` repo that was [moved to](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/1039) `corert` repo