# Out of memory error when compiling UWP app in release mode with .Net native

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, release, .net-native

I have a solution where my main project is a uwp app, and two other projects referenced by the app :

1. UWP App ---> references 2.
2. Universal Class library ----> references 3.
3. PCL Library

2 --> uses EF7 and SQLight.

3 --> uses [PCLCrypto](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto)

Now, everything works just fine and excellent when I'm on Debug mode x86 targeting local machine.

I want to compile the solution in release mode using `.Net native tool chain`, here's my config :

[image]

When I launch the compilation, it takes a remarkably long time, and too much memory is consumed by the .Net native tools :

[image]

After some time, everything stops with 2 errors on visual studio :

[image]

Here's what the output window says :

> 1>------ Build started: Project: ServerCommunication, Configuration:
>   Release Any CPU ------ 1>  ServerCommunication ->
>   C:\Users\aymen\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Applinova\Liberte\ServerCommunication\bin\Release\ServerCommunication.dll
>   2>------ Build started: Project: NewspaperDataLayer, Configuration:
>   Release x86 ------ 2>C:\Users\aymen\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Applinova\Liberte\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(225,5):
>   warning : All projects referencing ServerCommunication.csproj must
>   install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317569. 2>  NewspaperDataLayer
>   -> C:\Users\aymen\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Applinova\Liberte\NewspaperDataLayer\bin\x86\Release\NewspaperDataLayer.dll
>
> ### 3>------ Build started: Project: Liberte, Configuration: Release x86

--some warnings here that I just skipped

> 3>  Starting .NET Native compilation 3>  Processing application code
>   3>C:\Users\aymen\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Applinova\Liberte\Liberte\Resources.System.Linq.Expressions.rd.xml(35):
>   warning : Method 'CreateLambda' within
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' could not be found.
>   3>C:\Users\aymen\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Applinova\Liberte\Liberte\Resources.System.Linq.Expressions.rd.xml(91):
>   warning : Method 'ParameterIsAssignable' within
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' could not be found. 3>  Computing
>   application closure and generating interop code 3>  Generating
>   serialization code 3>  Compiling interop code 3>  Cleaning up
>   unreferenced code 3>  Generating native code 3>STARTPROCESSTASK :
>   error : Out of Memory 3>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1129,5):
>   error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe
>   @"C:\Users\aymen\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Applinova\Liberte\Liberte\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\Liberte.rsp"'
>   returned exit code 1
>   ========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

What would possibly be wrong with this please ??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (I am also using EF7 and other libraries) but I solved using [Visual Studio 15 preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs15-preview-vs.aspx) (it is not visual studio 2015 update 2, which I didn't try). They improved the .NET native tools so now you should not have any problem, even if using a lot of third party library.

**UPDATE**

I have solved all my issues after i have installed visual studio 2015 update 3 and switched from EF7 to [EF core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap) also available via nuget

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggled past few days around trying to fix this problem, but currently there is no easy solution for it.

There is a closed Issue on EF7 github, more info here (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4387) where they suggest as solution update EF7 to v1.0.0-rc2-16898.

I didn't manage how to update and as it still a nightly version, my final solution ("fast" workaround) was change my entire DB to sqlite-pcl (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4913e7d5-96c9-4dde-a1a1-69820d615936).

If you aren't in a rush to lunch your application, you can always wait until final version of RC2 it should be done during April.

Comment: Thx for your answer, Wll actually, I switched from sqlite-pcl to EF7, sqlite-pcl was really painful for me, from the point that I had to use the extensions and all that to have a good ORM experience, EF7 was much better for me, to be honest the problem was resolved for me, after several days by fixing the directives in the Default.rd.xml file, but still I couldn't have a clear explanation for this, the only thing I can say, is that .Net native still needs lots of work to be done, it's really painful and its team needs really the feedback of the community to fix the problems.

Comment: Can you share your Default.rd.xml? Maybe it can fix my problem.