# Error Creating UWP store package or Release Build - Out of Memory

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, .net-native, visual-studio-2017

Want to submit my app to the windows store but I am getting compile errors.
If I try to create a `Release Build` or if i try `Create App Packages` of my app I eventually get the following.

> ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\Users\garet\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestUwpProject\TestUwpProject\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\TestUwpProject.rsp"' returned exit code 1
>
> Out of Memory

Things I have tried.

- Move the project to a different drive
- Recreate the project
- Move project to a different device (Laptop).

Note:- my laptop I tried it on is running VS2017 RC and the latest insider preview of windows 10.

The only thing i can note is that if I create a blank project and add all the nuget packages etc it compiles fine which seem to mean an issue with my code but I wouldn't know where to start.

Issue looks similar to this but I am not using EF.

[Out of memory error when compiling UWP app in release mode with .Net native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162610/out-of-memory-error-when-compiling-uwp-app-in-release-mode-with-net-native)

Comment: And when using VS2015? Does the Store even accept packages made with 2017 or preview builds?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 is on my primary my PC. VS 2017 on my laptop was just a test to see if it was an issue with Visual Studio.

Comment: None of that follows from the question. Use the _edit_ link to improve it.

Comment: Which question? Your question in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear it's causing you trouble. It's a bit difficult to diagnose without more information but it's most likely that one of our “whole program” analysis phases has exploded exponentially in memory. The most common frameworks that we see this happen with are EF and the Syncfusion libraries. Working around the bug will depend on the specifics of your program but hopefully a bit of twiddling will get you back on your feel.

The easiest thing to attempt is to try to remove dlls that you're not actually dependent on. Fewer libraries in, fewer things to have the compiler think about. This is particularly useful for the Syncfusion libraries as their entire stack is in one Nuget package but most folks only use a small slice of the functionality there.

If that's not successful, you can get help from us more directly by sending a mail to dotnetnative@microsoft.com. Please send along an [ILCRepro](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/ilcRepro.md) file as it's the fastest way for us to help out.

We’ve made progress correcting some of these issues but some of the confounding factors require architectural level changes to the compiler that are still ~1 year out.

Disclaimer: I work on the .NET Native compiler+runtime team.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did solve this. It looks like it was a syncfusion dll. I used ReSharper to remove unused references and saw it was removed. Compiling worked fine after.
It's odd because when I created a blank project and added Syncfusion it compiled fine.

Comment: Glad to hear you're back on your feet. As you may imagine, the non-linearity of various analysis phases can mean that the addition of a few dlls with "interesting" patterns can cause us to run out of control. Feel free to let us know if you run into any other difficulty.